# How to wait code execute when use curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a code

```
for($i=1;;$i++){
    //curl my function... I have set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=600, this return content of url
    $site= $this->curl_function('http://example.com/'.$i);

    //filtering everything I need
    preg_match_alL('/<a href="(.+?)">(.+?)<\/a>/mis',$site,$match,PREG_SET_ORDER);

    //if url not content then exit
    if(isset($match['0']['2'])) exit;
}
```

My question is how to wait curl,preg_match_all execute then exit...
My code alway exit when $i=1 or $i=2.
Thank!

Comment: This always waits. It's no asynchronous or anything. I guess your question is not clear to me.

Comment: is `preg_match_alL` a copy paste error?

Comment: preg_match_all good, but i write have error!

Comment: $match['0']['2'] alway show and hide... i think if() not wait preg_match_all() and curl(), sorry my english bad

Comment: but oke, i have did it :) tks GolezTroll and Class very much